# Using svg-pan-zoom from es6 with webpack

Tags: svg, webpack, ecmascript-6

How can I use `svg-pan-zoom` from es6 with webpack? I tried something like this:

```
import {svgPanZoom} from '../node_modules/svg-pan-zoom/src/svg-pan-zoom.js;
```

But `svgPanZoom` is `undefined`. I also tried simply:

```
import * as svg_pan_zoom from 'svg-pan-zoom';
```

But then `svg-pan-zoom` was set to `{}`;

Comment: did you ever find a fix for this?

Comment: @KFE Yep! Posted it as the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was:

```
import svgPanZoom from "svg-pan-zoom/src/svg-pan-zoom.js";
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

`import svgPanZoom from 'svg-pan-zoom'`